# Phonegap File Transfer - how to insert a loading .gif while loading the file

Tags: javascript, cordova, file-transfer

I've got this Javascript code for my phonegap application for downloading a soundfile into the Ringtones folder. Since it can take while downloading it and until the alert pops up, I'd like to insert a .gif while the file is downloading.. How can i do this? This is my code:

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
fileTransfer.download(
"http://example.com/Sound.mp3",
"file://sdcard/Ringtones/Sound.mp3",
function(entry) {
    alert("Sound downloaded!" );
},
function(error) {
    alert("download error source " + error.source);
    alert("download error target " + error.target);
    alert("upload error code" + error.code);
});
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have this where you want on your page:

```
<div id="loadingImg" style="display:none;">
    <img src="load.gif" />
</div>
```

then display/hide it at relevant points in your code (perhaps using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)):

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

//Fade in the loadingImg Div at the start of your function
$("loadingImg").fadeIn();

fileTransfer.download(
    "http://example.com/Sound.mp3",
    "file://sdcard/Ringtones/Sound.mp3",
    function(entry) {

        //Fade out the loadingImg Div on success
        $("loadingImg").fadeOut();
        alert("Sound downloaded!");
    },
    function(error) {

        //Fade out the loadingImg Div on error
        $("loadingImg").fadeOut();
        alert("download error source " + error.source);
        alert("download error target " + error.target);
        alert("upload error code" + error.code);
    });
}
```